# What are the smallest and largest values of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let v and w be two vectors with ||v|| = 3 and ||w|| = 4. What is the largest and smallest possible values of v · w?

I found this question in the textbook and I'm not sure how to solve this since I just started linear algebra. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $|v\cdot w|\leq \|v\|\|w\|$.

Comment: First, find a formula relating $\|v\|,\|w\|,v\cdot w$ and the cosine of the angle between $v$ and $w$. Then, use it.

Comment: cos = ((v · w)/ ∥v∥ * ∥w∥)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one you want.  Now, what are the largest and smallest values that a cosine can have?

Comment: -1 and 1, so the dot product of v and w can only be a max of 12 and a min of -12?

Comment: Good. Now you can write up an answer and, after a while, you can accept it, if you want to. May seem strange, but it's actually encouraged.

Comment: You should mention that you work with a inner product space over the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $||v+w||^2=|| v||^2+ ||w||^2+2(v\cdot w)$.  The smallest possible value of $||v+w||^2$ is $1$, when the vectors are pointing in opposite directions, and the largest possible value is $49$, when they point in the same direction.

Comment: Yes but I was looking for the smallest and largest values for v · w to which im pretty sure is -12 and 12

Comment: Indeed. Look above. Smallest value of $||v+w||^2$ is $1$, so smallest value of $2(v\cdot w)$ is $1-9-16=-24$, so smallest value of $v\cdot w$ is $-24/2$. Largest possible value of $||v+w||^2$ is $49$, so largest value of $2(v\cdo w)$ is $49-9-16=24$. largest value of $v\cdot w$ is $24/2$.